# Firecracker vs ACRN?

Tags: virtualization, containers, hypervisor

What is the main difference between the [ACRN](https://github.com/projectacrn/acrn-hypervisor)  and the [firecracker](https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker) hypervisors ?

As I understand, [ACRN](https://github.com/projectacrn/acrn-hypervisor)

> The ACRN Hypervisor is a Type 1 reference hypervisor stack, running directly on the bare-metal hardware, and is suitable for a variety of IoT and embedded device solutions.

Only on the embedded devices, why ?

As I understand, [Firecracker](https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker)

> Firecracker runs workloads in lightweight virtual machines, called microVMs, which combine the security and isolation properties provided by hardware virtualization technology with the speed and flexibility of containers.

My questions:

1. But where is the other **key** differences ?

   - The ACRN is 1-st type, while the Firecracker the 2 type.
   - Both of them are use the VMM (virtual machine manager).
   - The Firecracker use the KVM, whereas the ACRN use the own ACRN hypervisor.
2. For which cases are these solutions most suitable ? Why ?
3. What is the difference in performance ?

I would like to use one of these solutions as part of the [Kata Containers](https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers).

Here is a useful [comparison](https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers/blob/2fc7f75724ac9e18e60f63dcc9aa395dc51c184d/docs/hypervisors.md#choose-a-hypervisor) of hypervisors.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for either of them? It does say that Firecracker is already integrated with Kata Containers. You can move on now.

Comment: Yep, I read. But the main question is not how to use it with the kata. But what is the difference between them ?